# kusto query to show the third column after using distinct for two other columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Hi I m trying to display ingestedtime in my below Kusto query, can you pls provide suggestion

```
find withsource=source in (cluster(X).database('y*').['TextFileLogs'])
where AttemptedIngestTime > ago(7d)
and FileLineContent contains "<li>Build Number:" 
| distinct source , FileLineContent //, AttemptedIngestTime
| extend databaseName = extract(@"""(oci-[^""]*)""", 1, source)
| extend BuildNumber = extract(@"([A-Z]\w*\.[0-9]\d*\.[0-9]\d*\.[0-9]\d*)",1,FileLineContent)
| extend StampVersion = extract(@"([0-9]\d*\.[0-9]\d*\.[0-9]\d*\.[0-9]\d*)",1,FileLineContent)
| extend cluster = X
//| extend IngestedTime = AttemptedIngestTime
|  summarize NumberOfRuns=count() by BuildNumber , StampVersion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could replace `distinct source, FileLineContent` with `summarize min(AttemptedIngestTime) by source, FileLineContent`

- or replace `min` with `max`, depending on the semantics you want)

then, you'll still need to decide how you aggregate it in your final `summarize` (either as `min(AttemptedIngestTime)`, or as a group by key, e.g. `startofday(AttemptedIngestTime)`)

---

regardless, you should consider following [query best practices](https://aka.ms/kusto.query-best-practices), and:

1. replace usage of `contains` with `has`.
2. replace usage of `extract` with `parse`.